# How can I add additional tags in a link in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The following code:

```
<%= link_to content_tag(:span, 'foo'), :action => 'new' %>
```

Renders the link like this:

```
<a href="/new"><span>foo</span></a>
```

I would like to add the bold tags after the ending span tag like this:

```
<a href="/new"><span>foo</span><b></b></a>
```

How can I add the  tags after the ending span tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass `link_to` a block instead of a string param:

```
<%= link_to :action => 'new' do %>
  <span>foo</span>
  <strong></strong>
<% end %>
```

**Note**: If you're on Rails 2.3 or earlier, use:

```
<% link_to :action => 'new' do %>
```

Comment: I tried it, but I keep getting a compile error: syntax error, unexpected ')' ...link_to :action => 'new' do ).to_s); @output_buffer.concat ...

Comment: @Amy If you're on Rails2.3, use `<%` instead of `<%=`

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem :)